# Как собрать package в python в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я новичек полный. И сделал вот свою пакейдж с програмкой своей. Вот он
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне его сложить в exe? Просто смотрел кучу всего, но непонимаю как это делается вообще. Можете пояснить зелёному как это лучше сделать. Или чтобы был exe файл запуска и ещё там папка мол с разными файлами как библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то самое простое решение - воспользоваться Pyinstaller'ом.

В консоле cmd установите эти два пакета через pip:

```py
pip install pypiwin32
pip install pyinstaller
```

После чего просто запустите эту команду в консоли cmd, указав путь и имя файла:

```py
pyinstaller base.py
```

Некоторые полезны опции сборки:

*--onefile* — сборка в один файл, т.е. файлы .dll не пишутся

*--windowed* -при запуске приложения, будет появляться консоль

*--noconsole* — при запуске приложения, консоль появляться не будет

*--icon=app.ico* — добавляем иконку в окно

*--paths* — возможность вручную прописать путь к необходимым файлам, если pyinstaller не может их найти

Пример такой команды сборки:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=name.ico --noconsole base.py
```

Comment: Не верно поняли. Есть пакейдж calculator и в нем вспомогательный functions. Все это вместе нужно собрать. Вроде какой-то setup.py нужно делать

Comment: Pyinstaller собирает все связанные пакеты. Запакуйте главный файл, в котором эти пакеты используются

Comment: А можете пример показать?

Comment: Пример чего? Использование можно на ютубе посмотреть. В противном случае мне нужен сам код, чтобы показать как его паковать

Comment: Киньте тогда Ютуб пожалуйста

Comment: https://youtu.be/AUH2yNY6TI4

Comment: `--onefile — сборка в один файл, т.е. файлы .dll не пишутся` - не правда. Все файлы (в том числе dll) собираются так же в папку, а потом архивируются и крепятся к exe. Получается что-то типа самораспаковывающегося архива, при запуске все распаковывается во временную папку, и оттуда запускается.